# json.loads() fails on my data read from a socket

Tags: json, python-3.x, server

i got some problems with my code. After i read a JSON received via socket by a Qt client in a python server, i want to get all the fields of that JSON so i can use it, but i got an error like this: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). This is the code that cause the exception to raise.

```
data = connection.recv(1024)
temp = data.decode("utf-8")
jdata = json.loads(temp)
```

The exception is raised by json.loads(temp). I tried to be sure to have the right type for the loads function, i tried to copy the same string that i get from the socket into another str type and the function works well. Does anyone knows if there is something i overlooked?

update: I just found out that the JSON i get from the socket have a size that differs from a string with the same characters

Comment: having a size that differs from a string with same characters sounds like non ascii characters (ones that take more than 1 byte to represent) is it possible your data isn't actually encoded as UFT-8? It said it failed at the very first character so maybe you have a non printable character at the beginning of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exception "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" usually indicates that the data you're trying to load is not valid JSON.

See [Python JSON Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

> "If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a JSONDecodeError will be raised." (Scroll down to json.loads function)

Can you print out your temp variable? You'll be able to see the value you're trying to JSONDecode.

Comment: Yes, you are right, in fact the JSON was not valid, because even if the data that print out was "clean", Qt seems to create some junk bytes that made the JSON invalid